# c# Return value of function non-existent, when returning a dictionary

Tags: c#

I have an interesting problem, which is a function that returns a `Dictionary<String,HashSet<String>>`.

The function converts some primitive structs to a Dictionary Class.

The function is called as follows:

```
Dictionary<String, HashSet<String>> Myset = new Dictionary<String,HashSet<String>>();
Myset = CacheConverter.MakeDictionary(_myList);
```

Upon execution of the two lines above, Myset is non-existent to the debugger.  Adding a watch results in:

> "The name 'Myset' does not exist in
>   the current context"

```
public Dictionary<String, HashSet<String>> MakeDictionary(LightWeightFetchListCollection _FetchList) 
{
    Dictionary<String, HashSet<String>> _temp = new Dictionary<String, HashSet<String>>();
    // populate the Dictionary
    // return
    return _temp;    
}
```

The Dictionary `_temp` is correctly populated by the called function and `_temp` contains all the expected values.

The problem seems to be with the dictionary not being returned at all.

Examples I could find on the web of functions returning primitive `Dictionary<string,string>` work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things,

First, don't initialize the `Myset` with a new empty instance. The preferred way is to assign the result of the method call.

```
var Myset = CacheConverter.MakeDictionary(_myList);
```

Second, the odds are very strong that you are running in release mode. Typically the compiler will remove any code that is not being used.

Comment: Yes, the debugger was hiding it from me, since I wasn't actually using Myset anywhere futher in code.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side question, why are you creating a new `Dictionary<String,HashSet<String>>` and then discarding it?

Anyway, your code should be fine - I suspect it's something in the debugger that's playing up. The watch would only be able to see the variable when you're in the relevant method of course, given that it's a local variable.

Leaving the debugger aside from the moment, does the code actually *run* as expected?

Comment: Hi Jon,

Yes it's the debugger that was to smart for me!  I created code further down to actually prints the values of the Dictionary and there it was!

I must admit that I am very new to C#,  where am I creating the Dictionary<String,HashSet<String>> and discarding it?

Comment: @twiga, you might have better luck if you changed your comment to read @Jon instead of Hi Jon.  I think it will appear in his SO email.